# (e107) datestamp incorrect

Tags: mysql, content-management-system

I just installed e107 v2 to my web host. I made a single new post on the homepage, but the time shows up as `15 Dec 2012 : 17:00`. I can't find any other settings for it in the admin panel, just the formatting itself. I also can't seem to find any other known issues about it with e107. I made sure the timezone is correct, but that won't account for the year difference. Any ideas how to correct this ? The installation is automated, it does not ask for any user input except for mysql database credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it here http://localhost/e107_admin/prefs.php#nav-core-prefs-date Change the localhost to your server address